# One line command to clear 8000 open port, killing django development server that run on background

Tags: python, django, port

when i try restart django server using CTRL+C on then run it

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

return:

```
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'project.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found this command work well without affect other python running application

```
netstat -tulpn |grep 8000|awk '{print $7}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs kill
```

Comment: or find all processes with `ps -al` and kill the process with `kill -9 PID` ,where PID is the server. I think it works

Answer (score 2):

One simple command line that you will never forget ;)

`fuser -k 8000/tcp`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use on OSX, where I search for 'runserver', rather than '8000' as sometimes I run things on non-default ports

`ps aux | grep runserver | grep -v 'grep' |awk '{print $2}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs kill`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line command to clear the port and restart django dev server:

```
sudo fuser -k <port_number>/tcp | python manage.py runserver <port_number>
```

`<port_number>` can be 8000 or so